# How to forward an existing outlook mail with new values from excel using vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I've an existing promotional mail with HTML formatting, colors, bullets etc. I would like to forward this mail to new set of recipients using VBA.

I've an existing mail with following Body:

---

Hi XXnameXX,

Some Picture are present & Lot of colored formatting.

Thanks for registering to our website. Your user id is XXuseridXX.

Thank you.

---

Here XXnameXX should be replaced with FirstName and XXuseridXX with userID

I am able to forward the selected mail from Outlook. But it's not forwarding it with all the images/formatting/bullets. On receiving end its showing a complete different mail with link and all.

```
Sub ForwardEmail()
 Dim oApp As Outlook.Application
 Dim objFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
 Set oApp = New Outlook.Application
 Set objNS = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
 Set objFolder = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
 Dim oEmail As Outlook.MailItem

 For Each objitem In Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection
     If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
         If objitem.Class = olMail Then

             Set myforward = objitem.Forward

             Set objRecip = myforward.Recipients.Add("firstlastname@gmail.com")

             myforward.HTMLBody = Replace(myforward.HTMLBody, "xxnamexx", "FirstName", 1, 1)

             myforward.Send

         End If
     End If
 Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, don't use multiple dots in the single line of code. I'd recommend breaking the chain of calls and declare each property or method call on separate lines of code.

```
If objFolder.DefaultItemType = olMailItem Then
```

There is no need to check out the folder's property in the loop each time. I'd suggest moving that condition out of the loop.

```
objitem.BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
```

Why do you need to set up the BodyFormat property? Did have a chance to check the value before setting the property?

```
myforward.Body = Replace(myforward.Body, "xxnamexx", "FirstName", 1, 1)
```

The [Body](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff865304(v=office.15).aspx) property is a string representing the clear-text body of the Outlook item. You need to use the [HTMLBody](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868941(v=office.15).aspx) property if you want to preserve the formatting. You can read more about all possible ways of working with item bodies in the [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx).

Anyway, I don't see the code where you add images and other information to the message body.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Now I'm using the myforward.HTMLBody property. But the problem I'm facing is that on receiving end the whole html email formatting is getting disturbed. To make it clear, I already have one mail in my inbox with all the pictures and formatting. I'm just forwarding that mail using VBA. We don't need to add any images while sending the mail.

Comment: Why do you need to set the BodyFormat property in the code?

Comment: Now I've removed that BodyFormat line from my code. I've modified it in my question. But still on receiving end it's completely disturbing the format of my mail. Like All the images it is giving as an attachment.

Comment: Make sure that the PR_ATTACH_CONTENT_ID property is set on attachments and you refer to the image through the cid img attribute. See [how to embed image in html body in c# into outlook mail](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c063b27-7e8a-4963-ad5f-ce7e5ffb2c64/how-to-embed-image-in-html-body-in-c-into-outlook-mail?forum=vsto) for more information.

Comment: I didn't get your comment. The existing email is perfect in formatting. Now I'm using VBA code to forward the existing mail. The code works well. But the whole email body is coming with different image attachment on receiving email ID. I want the forwarded mail as it is in the receiving mailbox. I hope I'm clear.